# Unable to create alias on Shared Mailbox in O365 after hybrid join

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hybrid, azure-hybrid-connections

I'm looking for the best practicee on how to add alias, before joining to hybrid I could add alias for single or shared account in O365/Exchange online but after hybrid join, I cannot see a way to add alias for shared account in O365. Each time I add alias for shared account in O365/Exchange I gets a error says  "We couldn't save your changes. Please try again. "If I would like to add alias for user account, I cannot do it via the O365/Exchange online, I have to go to local AD>User>user attribute>Proxy address> smtp:alias@domain.com that's how I can get alias for user accounts

My environment: 
One AD forest with One Domain (local)
1 O365 Tenant with 25 domains

There isn't on-premise Exchange server. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to add an alias to shared account in o365 if we have Hybrid join.?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have to go to local AD>User>user attribute>Proxy address> smtp:alias@domain.com that's how I can get alias for user accounts

This is the only way that you can add aliases for email accounts for those users that you create on-premises if you create the shared mailbox directly on your Exchange Online and managed the aliases directly on your Exchange Online web

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to write, Yes I know that. 

I don't have exchange on-premises server, I only have exchange online.  

What I'm trying to find is how to create alias for shared mailboxes created before hybrid join as I can't add any alias for them in o365 and they are not in on-premises AD.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add alias to my shared mailbox. I was getting error saying domain is not accepted. after digging I found one of the shared mailbox had an alias and the alias domain doesn't exist in my environment anymore.

after removing that alia I could add more into to all shared mailbox.